# How do I configure a JDBC data source in JBoss AS 5.1.0.GA?

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, jndi, jboss5.x

Could somebody point me at or post an example of configuring a data source for JBoss 5.1.0.GA?

I am getting the following error when I try to hook up a data source to my web application in JBoss 5.1.0.GA using JNDI.

> startup failed due to previous errors java.lang.RuntimeException: mapped-name is required for jdbc/jos of deployment jos-services-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war

My **/WEB-INF/web.xml** contains the following resource reference:

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/jos</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

I have configured **/META-INF/jboss-web.xml** as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web
    xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_5_1.xsd"
    version="5.1">
    <context-root>/services</context-root>
    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/jos</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <jndi-name>java:jos</jndi-name>
    </resource-ref>
</jboss-web>
```

And the **jos-ds.xml** file that defines the data source is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE datasources
    PUBLIC "-//JBoss//DTD JBOSS JCA Config 5.0//EN"
    "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-ds_5_0.dtd">
<datasources>
    <xa-datasource>
        <jndi-name>jos</jndi-name>
        <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
        <xa-datasource-property name="URL">${ie.courts.jos.datasource.url}</xa-datasource-property>
        <user-name>${ie.courts.jos.datasource.username}</user-name>
        <password>${ie.courts.jos.datasource.password}</password>
        <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
        <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
        <blocking-timeout-millis>2000</blocking-timeout-millis>
        <idle-timeout-minutes>2</idle-timeout-minutes>
        <track-connection-by-tx />
        <valid-connection-checker-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.MySQLValidConnectionChecker</valid-connection-checker-class-name>
        <exception-sorter-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.MySQLExceptionSorter</exception-sorter-class-name>
        <!--new-connection-sql></new-connection-sql-->
        <!--check-valid-connection-sql></check-valid-connection-sql-->
        <metadata>
            <type-mapping>mySQL</type-mapping>
        </metadata>
    </xa-datasource>
</datasources>
```

The stack trace that I get is:

```
14:17:17,573 ERROR [StandardContext] Context [/jos-services-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT] startup failed due to previous errors java.lang.RuntimeException: mapped-name is required for jdbc/jos of deployment jos-services-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war
       at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.injection.WebResourceHandler.loadXmlResourceRefs(WebResourceHandler.java:178)
       at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.injection.WebResourceHandler.loadXml(WebResourceHandler.java:327
       at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatInjectionContainer.processMetadata(TomcatInjectionContainer.java:550)
       at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.WebCtxLoader.start(WebCtxLoader.java:158)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4272)
       at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:310)>
       at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:142)
       at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
       at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118)
       at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
       at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
       at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
       at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88) 
       at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
       at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
       at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
       at $Proxy38.start(Unknown Source)
       at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
       at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
       at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:286)
       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
       at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
       at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
       at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
       at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
       at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
       at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
       at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
       at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
       at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
       at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
       at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1178)
       at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
       at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
       at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
       at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
       at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
       at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
       at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:361)
       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
       at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:306)
       at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:271)
       at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
       at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
       at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

Comment: I ended up switching the project to JBoss AS6. It was a proof-of-concept so I had some flexibility from the customer with regard to changing the platform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That error is misleading, at least in my case, and the actual culprit being the XSD version. Change the XSD 5.1 to DTD 5.0 and it no more complain about the `mapped-name`.

*Below is the `WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml` I m using now: (jboss-web.xml needs to be `WEB-INF` of your webapp)*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>                                                                                                                             
<!DOCTYPE jboss-web PUBLIC
        "-//JBoss//DTD Web Application 5.0//EN"
        "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-web_5_0.dtd">
<jboss-web>
<context-root>/context_name</context-root>
    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/jndi_name</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <jndi-name>java:jndi_name</jndi-name>
    </resource-ref>
</jboss-web>
```

*Though this is some what old question, I m mentioning how I solved the same issue with JBoss 5.1.0 GA, so that someone may find it useful*

Answer (score 0):

Souldn't you use such JNDI name (in `jboss-web.xml`  file):

```
<jndi-name>java:/jos</jndi-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jboss-web should look like:

```
<jboss-web>
    <!-- ... -->
    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/jos</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <jndi-name>java:/jos</jndi-name>
    </resource-ref>
</jboss-web>
```

Reference: http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5/html-single/Administration_And_Configuration_Guide/index.html Figure 6.14